# how to generate randomly football matches in .net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

as you can see I have ten team in my database, and here's my code, now I want to generate randomly matches in asp.net C#

in this code the problem is that "d" is a list and the return type of Data is object,
the the picture of error is below.

note in database team_id and team_name in relation when you call team id team_name will be show or call.

function is in service and service is calling in controller.

```
[HttpGet("DoMatch")]
        public IActionResult DoMatch()
        {
            
            var res= _matchService.DoMatch();
            return Ok(res);
        }


public ResponseModel DoMatch()
        {
            var random = new Random();
            List<Team> list = _context.Team.ToList();
            Dictionary<int, List<Team>> d = new Dictionary<int, List<Team>> { };
            var count = list.Count();
            for (int i = 0; i < count / 2; i++)
            {
                List<Team> temp = new List<Team>();
                int index1 = random.Next(list.Count);
                temp.Add(list[index1]);
                list.RemoveAt(index1);
                int index2 = random.Next(list.Count);
                temp.Add(list[index2]);
                list.RemoveAt(index2);
                d.Add(i, temp);
            }

            return new ResponseModel
            {
                Data =  d,
                IsSuccess = true
            };
        }
```

the error or exception is:
System.NotSupportedException: The collection type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Fantasy_League.Models.Team]]' on 'FantasyLeague.Models.ViewModels.ResponseModel.Data' is not supported.

[image]

Comment: This image is unreadable. Post code as *text* not images. Images can't be copied, compiled, tested or googled

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: Post the *exception* as text as well. Besides, it looks like the exception has nothing to do with this code. This looks like a JSON serialization error. What matters in this case is the class and its properties

Comment: *"d" is a list* - I beg to differ. A List and a Dictionary are quite different

Comment: Since when are soccer matches "random" teams against each other? But anyway: Why not simply shuffle the list and get pairwise adjacent items? That would of course mean it has a count that meets %2 == 0.

Answer (score 2):

The actual problem that you're running into, as described by the exception message you're getting, is that `Dictionary<int, ...>` cannot be serialized to be sent back in the web response. JSON requires each key to be a string. So you'll need to decide what you actually want your model to look like. Most likely it would work just fine to use the Values from your dictionary.

```
    Data = d.Values,
```

That will make the JSON data come across as an array where each element is an array with the paired teams in it.

But Fildor makes a good point in his comment, that you could do this more easily by shuffling and pairing up adjacent teams:

```
    Data = list.OrderBy(t => random.Next()).Chunk(2);
```

Then all that fancy dictionary logic goes away.